# Splitting a string from a input without using strtok()

Tags: c

I have been working on a program to read zip codes and populations from a .csv file and find the zip code with the largest and smallest population. I'm tasked to do this without using scanf(all variants) and strtok(). Currently, it outputs the entire string and I do not know how to split the string into just zip code and population. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
int main(){
    int lines = 1024; //Maximum lines, specified
    char str[256]; //Maximum characters, specified
    char* pEnd = str;
    
    //Variables for parsing data
    char zipCode[256];
    char population[256];
    
    long bufPopulation = 0; //Variable to convert from string to long

    //Variables to track the number of zipcodes and total population
    static int NumOfZipCodes = 0;
    static long totalPopulation = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lines && fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); i++){
    
        //parses the data being read into variable 'str'
        strcpy(zipCode, str);
        strcpy(population, str);
    
        printf("String %s", str); //outputs str
        printf("Zip codes %s", zipCode); //outputs zipCode
        printf("Population %s", population); //outputs population
    
        if (i > 0){
            bufPopulation = strtol(population, &pEnd, 10);
    
            printf("Buffer population %.0ld", bufPopulation); //outputs the long value of population
            totalPopulation += bufPopulation;
            NumOfZipCodes++;
        }
    }
    int size = sizeof population/sizeof population[0];
    
    long maxPop, minPop = 0;
    char maxZip, minZip = zipCode[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        bufPopulation = strtol(population, &pEnd, 10);
    
        if (minPop > bufPopulation)
        {
            minPop = bufPopulation;
            minZip = zipCode[i];
        }
        if (maxPop < bufPopulation)
        {
            maxPop = bufPopulation;
            maxZip = zipCode[i];
        }
    }
    
    //Displays the stored values
    printf("Total Population across %d zipcodes is ", NumOfZipCodes);
    printf("%.0ld\n", totalPopulation);
    
    printf("The fewest people live in %.0d, population ", minZip);
    printf("%.0ld\n", minPop);
    
    printf("The most people live in %.0d, population ", maxZip);
    printf("%.0ld\n", maxPop);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're copying the same `str` into both `zipCode` and `population`. Where is your code that looks for the separator between them?

Comment: You can use `strchr()` to look for the comma.

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. I intended to place it in the first for loop, the one that adds the string to zipCode and population, in the space prior to copying. The string is separated by ','. I was thinking if(str[i] != ",") but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh so if(strchr(str) != ','){ add str to zipCode[]}?

Comment: `strchr(str, ',')` returns a pointer to the first `','` character in `str`. You want to copy everything before that to `zipCode`, and copy everything after it to `population`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample of `.csv` file which contains zip codes and populations?

Comment: Line 1: Zip Code Total Population Median Age Total Males Total Females Total Households Average Household Size
Line 2: 93535 72046 28.3 34879 37167 20672 3.44

Comment: Thank you for providing the input sample. Are the columns are separated by a whitespace, not a comma?

Comment: they are separated by commas

Comment: Then why can't we see any commas in your input sample?

Answer (score 0):

The `strtol()` function assigns `endptr`, which is pointed by the second
argument, to the address of the remaining string *after* converting the valid
substring into the long integer. The character pointed by the address will
be normally the delimiter or the newline character at the end of the string.
Then you can repeat calling `strtod()` and skipping the delimiter to parse
the columns of the csv line. Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHARS 256                            // max characters in a line
#define DELIM ' '                               // column delimiter

int main() {
    char str[MAXCHARS];                         // line buffer
    char *eptr;                                 // pointer within str

    int zip, minZip, maxZip;
    long pop, minPop, maxPop;
    int numOfZipCodes = 0;
    long totalPopulation = 0;

    fgets(str, MAXCHARS, stdin);                // read the header and discard
    while (fgets(str, MAXCHARS, stdin)) {       // read each line
        zip = (int)strtol(str, &eptr, 10);      // parse the zip code
        if (*eptr != DELIM) {                   // check the next delimiter
            fprintf(stderr, "illegal input string: %s", str);
            exit(1);
        }
        while (*eptr == DELIM) eptr++;          // skip the delimiter
        pop = strtol(eptr, &eptr, 10);          // parse the population
        if (*eptr != DELIM) {                   // check the next delimiter
            fprintf(stderr, "illegal input string: %s", str);
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Zip code %d\n", zip);           // output zip code
        printf("Population %ld\n", pop);        // output population

        if (numOfZipCodes == 0) {               // initialize values on the 1st line
            minPop = maxPop = pop;
            minZip = maxZip = zip;
        } else {
            if (minPop > pop) {
                minPop = pop;
                minZip = zip;
            }
            if (maxPop < pop) {
                maxPop = pop;
                maxZip = zip;
            }
        }
        totalPopulation += pop;
        numOfZipCodes++;
    }

    // display the results
    printf("Total Population across %d zipcodes is %ld\n", numOfZipCodes, totalPopulation);
    printf("The fewest people live in %d, population %ld\n", minZip, minPop);
    printf("The most people live in %d, population %ld\n", maxZip, maxPop);

    return 0;
}
```

It assumes the delimiter is a whitespace as shown in your comment. If the
deimiter is a comma or other character, modify the `#define DELIM ' '` line
accordingly.